# Internal HDD disconnects (randomly?)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, power-supply, connection

A few weeks ago, in my computer I had 2 SSD (120Go each) and 1 HDD (2To). On one of my SSD I had Windows 8 installed but I was running out of memory so I bought a new SSD (500G0) and I installed Windows 10 on it.

Since that, my 2To HDD keeps disconnecting... As I have several operating systems I tried to boot on each one to see if the problem was Windows 10 but it was still the same. I also bought a new SATA cable but still the same. Sometimes the HDD appears but it disconnects when I launch apps like Android Studio or Spotify. Sometimes it doesn't even appear in the BIOS at the boot.

So my guesses are:

1. The HDD is broken
2. Maybe the power supply isn't enough (I have a 700W power supply)

Here is a full dump of my computer's configuration: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/6mw28KtaY4KBvWlx1Z66AjY

I thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is the S.M.A.R.T report I got using this tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/

```
C:\Users\Omar>smartctl -A D:\
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win10] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   131   131   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       108
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   124   124   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       554 (Average 614)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1818
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   121   121   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       35
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6270
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1185
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1820
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1820
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   230   230   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 16/56)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
```

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the smart data.